# Why is my onclick function not modifying the state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of products and i have with a function to open a modal of the selected product and a another function to close the modal.

This is my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import aviator from '../../assets/images/aviator.jpg'
import roundFleck from '../../assets/images/roundfleck.jpg'
import wayfarer from '../../assets/images/wayfarer.jpg'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion' 


const ProductList = () => {
  const [ selectedId, setSelectedId ] = useState(null)
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const productsPerPage = 8;

  // Array of products

  const indexOfLastProduct = currentPage * productsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstProduct = indexOfLastProduct - productsPerPage;

  // Get the products for the current page
  const currentProducts = products.slice(indexOfFirstProduct, indexOfLastProduct);

  const modalRef = useRef()
```

Receive the id of the clicked product set it and set the value to setIsOpen to true. This works fine the clicked product modal is open

```
  const handleCardClick = (id) => {
    setSelectedId(id);
    setIsOpen(true);
  };
```

As i click on the X button to close the button nothing happens. I console logged the values of selectedId which should be null but its still the id of the product and isOpen is still true instead of false.

```
  const handleCloseClick = () => {
    setSelectedId(null)
    setIsOpen(false);
    
  };

  const variants = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: .5
      
    },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
      transition: {
        duration: 2.5        
      }
    }
  }

  const itemVariants = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 0.8
    },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5
      }
    }
  }

  const selectedItemVariants = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 0.5
    },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5
      }
    }
  }  

  const selectedProduct = selectedId ? products.find((product) => product.id === selectedId) : null;

  const selectedProducts = selectedProduct ? [selectedProduct] : currentProducts;

  return (
    <div>
      <section className="featured">
        <h2>Featured Sunglasses</h2>
        <motion.div 
        className="cards"
        custom={{delay: 2}}
        initial='hidden'
        animate='visible'
        variants={variants}
        >
          {selectedProducts.map((product) => (
            <div
            key={product.id}
            onClick={() => handleCardClick(product.id)}
          >
            <motion.div
              className="card"
              layoutId={product.id}
              whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
              whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            >
              {isOpen ? <button onClick={() => handleCloseClick()}>X</button> : ''}
              <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
              <div className="card-content">
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
              </div>
            </motion.div>
          </div>
          ))}
        </motion.div>

       
        
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductList;
```

So for some reason as the function handleCloseClick is triggered in the X button the state value is not being modified. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. I also recommend that you install the React Dev Tools browser addon if you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click even is propagating.  Which means *both* `handleCloseClick` *and* `handleCardClick` are being invoked, and in that same order.  So the state is being updated to `false` *and* to `true` in the same re-render operation.

You can stop the event propagation by passing the click event to the function.  First, simplify the usage of the handler function so it automatically receives the event object:

```
onClick={handleCloseClick}
```

If you prefer the longer syntax or need to pass other arguments to the function, you still can:

```
onClick={e => handleCloseClick(e)}
```

Then in the function you can receive the event object and call a function on it:

```
const handleCloseClick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  setSelectedId(null)
  setIsOpen(false);
};
```